# Mapped interface with functions to a different return type preserving the call signature

Tags: typescript

I have a interface like this:

```
interface Foo {
  foo(a: string, b:number): string | number;
  bar(a: boolean): number;
}
```

And I need a mapped type with the same call signature on members and a different return type. Something like this:

```
// this is not a real type
interface_like_this "FooBoolean"
  foo(a: string, b: number): boolean
  bar(a: boolean): boolean;
```

Must be something like this, that preserve call signature and change return type

```
type ToBoolean<T> = { [...]: boolean };
```

And I will use like this:

```
const fooBar: ToBoolean<Foo> = {
  foo(a: string, b: number){ return true }, // type check OK
  bar(a: number) { return false } // type check FAIL, wrong 'a' parameter type
 }
```

I hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *conditional type*:

```
type ToBoolean<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any
    ? (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => boolean
    : never;
};
```

It requires the `Parameters` type available in TypeScript >= 3.1. If you're using an older version, you can create it yourself:

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  T extends (...args: infer P) => any
    ? P
    : never;
```

Comment: your solution is just what I need. Thanks!.